# Example of a non-commutative ring containing 4 elements

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

I need an example of a non-commutative ring containing 4 elements. I considered the following example of $M_2(Z_2)$ containing the following four elements:

$\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$

Here clearly the set is non-commutative. I have also checked that the set forms a ring. But I want to be sure whether the set forms a ring or not.
Can anyone tell me whether it is forming a ring or not?

***EDITS***

Previously the elements I chose were not closed under addition. So I replaced the identity element with another element and checked that now it is closed under addition as well as non commutative.
*Is it correct now?*

Comment: no, you need closure of addition as well as multiplication.

Comment: Your subset isn't closed under addition, as Will Jagy says. Also every ring with $4$ elements is commutative, unless your rings don't have identity.

Comment: Yeah! I also noticed it just now.

Comment: Can you provide me such an example?

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan Please check whether it's correct now

Comment: It's correct if your rings don't have identity. Personally I think this is a bad convention.